# DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(Cell cell) not working in java p o i

Tags: java, apache-poi

[image]

This my input in cell A4 there is a date. How can i get this in my java program as it is . My DateUtil.isCellDateFormated(Cell) not working .
i have used DataFormatter it is giving me no of days.
[image]

```
public String getDataValueAsString(Cell cell){
    String value = null;
    CellType type = cell.getCellTypeEnum();
    DataFormatter dataFormat = new DataFormatter();
    CreationHelper ch = null;
    switch(type){
        case BLANK:
            value = "";
            break;
        case BOOLEAN:
            value = String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case ERROR:
            value = dataFormat.formatCellValue(cell);
            break;
        case FORMULA:
            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            value = dataFormat.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
            break;
        case NUMERIC:
            if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                System.out.println("Cell is date formatted : ");
                ch = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
                short formatIndex = ch.createDataFormat().getFormat(cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString());
                System.out.println("format index : "+formatIndex);
                String format = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
                System.out.println("format : "+format);
            }else{
                //value = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                value = dataFormat.formatCellValue(cell);
            }
            break;
        case STRING:
            value = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
        default:
            value = dataFormat.formatCellValue(cell);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I am using poi 3.17 beta

Comment: What exactly is the output of your code when the `cell` is `A4`?

Comment: What is the cell type of cell `A4`, and what is the data format string applied to the cell? (Fetch via the Cell Style)

Comment: check the output and the cell type is date for sure because it is giving me the number of days .

Comment: nothing seems to work . I think there is a bug in the method DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(Cell) .. even the DataFormatter not giving me the formatted date.

Comment: and i cant use DateUtil.isValidExcelDate(double) to check whether the cell has a date or just some numeric value because it will convert every numeric value to date "1/1/1900+numeric value " ............... i am stuck here

Comment: Can you please check what `cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat()` returns?

Comment: cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString() returns null value

Comment: I had not asked about `getDataFormatString` but `getDataFormat`.

Comment: cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat() = 58

Comment: Where is this `Excel` file coming from? The number format id 58 (x3A) should only be used in special locales and it really *should* have a format string applied. So this is kinda a buggy `Excel` file.

Comment: yeah right it is not MSOffice excel workbook . This excel is created by some third party software. But now it works fine I have done some changing in CellStyle

Comment: cell.getCellStyle().getFormat() works fine

Comment: But why not DateUtil.isCellDateFormated(Cell) is working i have tested this method with original excel sheet also not working with "8/8/2017" type of dates.........

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can try to use [Cell.html#getDateCellValue()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue()) method.

Some quick example:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ExternalCaller {

    public static final String MM_DD_YYYY = "MM/dd/yyyy";

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\test.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                int cellType = cell.getCellType();
                try {
                    determineValue(cellType, cell);
                } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void determineValue(int cellType, Cell cell) {
        switch (cellType) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                determineDate(cell);
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This type of cell should be additionally implemented");
        }
    }

    private static void determineDate(Cell cell) {
        short dataFormat = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat();

        if (14 == dataFormat) {
            Date dateCellValue = cell.getDateCellValue();
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(MM_DD_YYYY).format(dateCellValue));
        } else {
            System.out.println(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell));
        }
    }
}
```

The output for the cell

[image]

will be:

```
123.0546
Killme
78%
11/22/1995
This type of cell should be additionally implemented
1190
```

Please let me know if it works for you, otherwise I will remove the answer.

Comment: but here we know the format but there can be n number of formats in a excel sheet how do keep that in check .Yes it is working for this cell but what if the format changes to "MM-d-YYYY" then .

Comment: your code might throw exception because every cell does not have date .

Comment: So you need to get formatting from the cell also and apply it for the date which will be received from excel?

Comment: Just updated the solution. Try this new version. I have checked several date formats and it seems working.

Comment: Thank you so much !... and btw what is "14" in condition 14==dataformat ..  i change the format to 58 now it work fine for me thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly this is numeric representation for each type of format in excel. Happy that it was helpful.

Comment: @Mr.Gabru What is 58 and 14? are those values are constant? any reference to the source file.